# Trying to remove a couple categories from shop page

Tags: plugins, categories

I have tried several snipits to remove two categories from the shop page of https://ornaments.com

```
function exclude_brands_from_related( $categories ){
    // array of category id's that should be excluded
    $exclude_cats = array( '4792', '2486');

    foreach( $categories as $index => $cat ){
        if( in_array( $cat->term_id, $exclude_cats ) ){
            unset($categories[$index]);
        }
    }

    return $categories;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_related_product_cat_terms', 'exclude_brands_from_related' );
```

and:

```
 add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_pre_get_posts_query' );

function custom_pre_get_posts_query( $q ) {



    if ( ! is_admin() && is_shop() && ! is_user_logged_in() ) {

        $q->set( 'tax_query', array(array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array( 'ethnic-ornaments','uncategorized' ), // Don't display products in these categories on the shop page
            'operator' => 'NOT IN'
        )));

    }

    remove_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_pre_get_posts_query' );

}
```

I am using the plugin Code Snipits to implement the code, but I have also tried to place it directly in the functions.php file to no avail.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

To alter products on shop page, you need to hook into `woocommerce_product_query` action:

```
/**
 * Exclude products from a particular category on the shop page
 */
function custom_pre_get_posts_query( $q ) {

    $tax_query = (array) $q->get( 'tax_query' );

    $tax_query[] = array(
       'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
       'field' => 'slug',
       'terms' => array( 'clothing' ), // Don't display products in the clothing category on the shop page.
       'operator' => 'NOT IN'
    );


    $q->set( 'tax_query', $tax_query );

}
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'custom_pre_get_posts_query' );
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I tried this code and replaced 'clothing' with 'ethnic-ornaments' and as you can see, it did not work:  https://dev-wp.ornaments.com/shop/